# How do I remove old options in Jquery when parent select box is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 chained select boxes using jquery and json.

Depending on first 2 values I filter third one my code actually works but the problem is when I change values of first 2 select boxes third select recieves new datas while keeping old ones.

I've tried to empty my array but it didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var makesArray = [];
  var selectedyear;
  var selectedcourse;

  var $yearDropDown = $("#DropDown_Year");
  var $course_type = $("#course_type");
  $yearDropDown.change(function() {
     selectedyear = this.value;
    //filter based on  selected year.  
});
        $course_type.change(function(){

   selectedcourse = this.value;
    makesArray = jQuery.grep(json, function(course, i) {
      return course.course_type == selectedcourse && course.year_code == selectedyear;
    })  
    var selectBox = document.getElementById('DropDown_Make');
for(var i = 0, l = makesArray.length; i < l; i++){
  var option = makesArray[i];
  selectBox.options.add( new Option(option.course_code, option.course_code, option.course_code) );
}
makesArray= []; //makesArray.empty(); 
});

});


<div id="DrpDwn">
  Year:
  <select id="DropDown_Year">
    <option>Yıl</option>
        <option value="15">2015-2016</option>
            <option value="16">2016-2017</option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-control" id="course_type" name="course_type" required>
    <option value="" selected> Choose</option>
    <option value="Yos">YÖS</option>
    <option value="SatMatGeo">SAT (MAT)</option>
    <option value="SatCriRea">SAT (ENG)</option>
    <option value="TomerABC">TÖMER (ABC)</option>
    <option value="TomerAB">TÖMER (AB)</option>
    <option value="TomerBC">TÖMER (BC)</option>
    <option value="TomerA1A2">TÖMER (A)</option>
    <option value="TomerB1B2">TÖMER (B)</option>
    <option value="TomerC1C2">TÖMER (C)</option>
  </select>
  Make:
  <select id="DropDown_Make">
    <option>None</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and this is **JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/rw7cb8c5/25/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `DropDown_Make` empty using `selectBox.innerHTML = ""` in `$course_type.change()` like following.

```
$course_type.change(function () {
    selectedcourse = this.value;
    makesArray = jQuery.grep(json, function (course, i) {
        return course.course_type == selectedcourse && course.year_code == selectedyear;
    })
    var selectBox = document.getElementById('DropDown_Make');

    selectBox.innerHTML = ""; //added this line

    for (var i = 0, l = makesArray.length; i < l; i++) {
        var option = makesArray[i];
        selectBox.options.add(new Option(option.course_code, option.course_code, option.course_code));
    }
    makesArray.empty();
});
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rw7cb8c5/26/)

Comment: it is worked thank you! 
one more thing after year code and course changed if user changes the year code it should empty third select box  because course code depends on year and course type.

Comment: You can use `$course_type.change();` in `$yearDropDown.change()`, that will be better than make third select box empty. See https://jsfiddle.net/rw7cb8c5/27/ @Rodrane